# matlab: waterfall plot non-square matrix

Tags: matlab, plot, dimensions

I am currently running some ffts and plotting the data in a waterfallplot via this code:

```
z = real(vec2mat(fftdata,100));
dim=size(z);

%create x, must be length of z
x=linspace(tmin, tmax,dim(1));

%create y, must be depth of z
y=linspace(fmin, fmax, dim(2));

wplot = waterfall(x,y,z);
```

I want to look at just the first z(:, 1:50), but the waterfall plot doesn't like non-square arrays as far as I can tell.

```
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not
consistent.

Error in waterfall (line 56)
z = [z0*ones(size(x,1),1) z(:,1) z z(:,size(z,2))
z0*ones(size(x,1),2) ];

Error in waterfallfunction (line 30)
wplot = waterfall(x,y,z);
```

Does anyone know a good way of overcoming this error? I've looked through a lot of questions here, so if I missed a duplicate, please send me that way. Zooming in doesn't quite work. The plot formatting gets messed up and the axis-es (axisies?) don't update (another problem I'd like help with if you're up for the challenge).
It's been a while since I worked with MatLab, so please let me know if there is any other information required.

Comment: seems like the dimension problem.. just try flipping coordinate vectors waterfall(y,x,z)

Comment: Well, I feel really stupid now. :) Thank you!